# rails_admin change boolean default icon true and false instead string 'true' and 'false'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin, rails-administrate

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2dXr.png)

I did created on one model with boolean field

```
rails g model saas reserved_seat:boolean
```

when i add new record it will show only ✓ , ✘ and ‒

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YrQn.png)

Instead i need to value display neither '**true**' or '**false**' nor '**ON**' or '**OFF' in** string

Comment: Well, why would you want to do that? Checkbox is anyday visually better than strings.

Comment: thank for your help,yes i understand Md. but i need that one,could you have any solution for this one

Comment: `i neead to value display neither 'true' or 'false' nor 'ON' or 'OFF' in string` you want them as strings or don't want to display it at all?

Comment: Thanks your help, i figured out the problem, i don't want them as string, i just need to list display On or Off thats it,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did was:

```
field :reserved_seat do
   pretty_value do
    if bindings[:object].reserved_seat==true
        %{<span style="color:blank;" >ON</span>}.html_safe
      else
        %{<span style="color:blank;" >OFF</span>}.html_safe
    end
  end
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer the documentation here [`wiki`](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Fields#overriding-field-type)

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.model 'Saas' do
    edit do
      field :reserved_seat, :string
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I did't changed boolean to string,i want to select the value with checkbox in my edit,but list field like display On or Off